# How to properly synchronize these threads?

Tags: c#, multithreading, locking, monitor

I'm trying to properly handle files in a web app. When downloading a file I lock on an object:

```
lock(lockObject)
{
   //Download file here.
}
```

so that if that same file is about to be deleted from another thread while in the middle of the download, the "delete" thread waits for the "download" thread to finish first:

```
lock(lockObject)
{
   //Delete file here.
}
```

This works, but presents another problem: two threads cannot download the file simultaneously.

How can I make it so that multiple threads can run the "download" code simultaneously but at the same time not allow any thread to run the "delete" code until the "download" threads are done?

I know the answer is somewhere in the `Monitor` class, but I'm not sure how to pull it off.

Comment: It's not clear how the download threads are distributing the task of downloading a single file... however that is, in any case, you would probably have a manager thread hold the lock and distribute work to its thread pool in some way.  That way the delete thread can wait on the lock held by the manager thread but the manager thread can do whatever it wants with its pool of workers.  Unless you mean something else by your question?  It's not terribly clear...more detail would help.

Comment: @J... I'm not sure what you're asking. The download code is run by regular threads from the thread pool provided by .NET when the user makes an HTTP request. The delete code is run by a cleanup job on the server side that runs every hour. In any case, I don't think any of that should matter.

Comment: No, the answer is not in the `Monitor` class. You could potentially use a [ReaderWriterLockSlim](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.readerwriterlockslim(v=vs.110).aspx) to allow multiple download threads, but force a delete thread to wait until all download threads are done. It's unclear to me, though, why you'd want to delete a file right after downloading it, or how you're going to have two different threads downloading the same file.

Comment: @JimMischel I'm not looking to delete the file right after downloading it; an attempt to delete the file can occur at any time, even in the middle of a download. And you can have two different threads downloading the same file simply by having two different users request the same file at the same time; this is common in web apps. Anyway, `ReaderWriterLockSlim` is exactly what I need.

Comment: You can solve that with a repository for the files that will manage all operations without a global lock.

Comment: @AxiomaticNexus It wasn't clear that this is a server app and that your "download" threads are actually *uploading* simultaneously.  This changes the meaning of the question dramatically.

Comment: @J... Yeah, it matters which side of the pipe you're on. When writing controllers for laboratory equipment, it gets confusing. What do you call the method that tells the external device to send its data? Some people call it "Upload" because the device is sending data. Others call it "Download" because the computer is receiving the data. People looked at me funny when I proposed naming the method, "GetDataFromDevice."

Comment: @JimMischel Omron does this... "Upload" means *"Get the program from the PLC"*... drives me nuts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Possibly a [ReaderWriterLockSlim](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.readerwriterlockslim(v=vs.110).aspx) would do what you need. Basically, you treat the download threads as readers and the delete threads as writers. You can have any number of readers, but any writer requires exclusive access. So if any file is being downloaded when the delete method calls `EnterWriteLock`, the delete thread will have to wait until all current downloads have finished.

```
ReaderWriterLockSlim theLock = new ReaderWriterLockSlim();

void Delete(filename)
{
    theLock.EnterWriteLock();
    try
    {
        // do delete stuff here
    }
    finally
    {
        theLock.ExitWriteLock();
    }
}

void Download(filename)
{
    theLock.EnterReadLock();
    try
    {
        // do delete stuff here
    }
    finally
    {
        theLock.ExitReadLock();
    }
}
```